Create a file/folder during a test with Jest always fails
I have a file watcher that triggers a callback every time a file in a specific path is update.
I want to write a test to make sure this happens, so my approach is the following:

create a temporary folder with a temporary file;
initialise the watcher;
update the file;
check that the watcher's callback is called with the correct parameters

Here's what I have so far:
    it("should call the file watcher callback with the correct attributes", async () => {
        try {
            const tempFile = path.join(__dirname, "test-file.txt");

            await fs.writeFile(tempFile, "initial content");

            const mockCallback = jest.fn();
            startFileWatcher([__dirname], mockCallback);
    
            await fs.appendFile(tempFile, 'new content');
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    
            const absolutePath = path.resolve(tempFile);
            expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('change', absolutePath);
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Test error:', error);
            throw error;
        } finally {
            // remove the file;
        }
    });

The problem is that I keep getting the error: console.error Test error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../tests/unit/test-file.txt'
I have also tried with this approach:
            const tempDirPath = path.join(__dirname, 'temp-folder-');
            const tempDir = await fs.mkdtemp(tempDirPath);
            const tempFile = path.join(tempDir, "test-file.txt");

But same result...how can I fix this? Also I need to run this test on github action, will I have a problem creating/manipulating the file system?

Where does the error come from? From fs.writeFile or from fs.appendFile?
